# Объявление компонента с атрибутом, отличным от modelValue, для v-model. Разница между modelValue и title

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, компоненты

Смотрел видеурок [Vue 3 фундаментальный курс от А до Я](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzLuMtDelGk&t=3686s) с 58:00-1:02:00. Там приведен следующий код

код формы с двумя `input`-ами

**PostForm.vue**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <h4>Создание поста</h4>
    <my-input
      v-focus
      v-model="post.title"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Название"
    />
    <my-input
      v-model="post.body"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Описание"
    />
    <my-button
      style="align-self: flex-end; margin-top: 15px"
      @click="createPost"
    >
      Создать
    </my-button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      post: {
        title: '',
        body: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createPost() {
      this.post.id = Date.now();
      this.$emit('create', this.post)
      this.post = {
        title: '',
        body: ''
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

</style>
```

код `input`-а

**MyInput.vue**

```
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="updateInput" class="input" type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-input',
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number]
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

</style>
```

***Реализация двустороннего связывания в `PostForm` и `my-input`***

Причем форма и инпут двусторонне связаны. См. код двустороннего связывания, который пригодится в дальнейшем

```
<my-input
  v-focus
  v-model="post.title"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Название"
/>
```

и

```
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="updateInput" class="input" type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-input',
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number]
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***Реализация двустороннего связывания в `ParentComponent` и `ChildComponent` из документации***

Также я нашел примеры двустороннего связывания на [Изменения в работе v-model](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80). Там приводится следующий код

```
<ChildComponent
  v-model:title="pageTitle"
  v-model:content="pageContent"
/>

<!-- будет сокращённой версией для: -->

<ChildComponent
  :title="pageTitle"
  @update:title="pageTitle = $event"
  :content="pageContent"
  @update:content="pageContent = $event"
/>


// ChildComponent.vue

export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: String // раньше было `value: String`
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  methods: {
    changePageTitle(title) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', title) // раньше было `this.$emit('input', title)`
    }
  }
}
```

***Переписывание кода двустороннего связывания (объявления/экспорта) в `ChildComponent` в стиле `my-input`***

**1.** Как переписать **объявление (экспорт)** `ChildComponent` в стиле компонента `my-input`

```
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="updateInput" class="input" type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-input',
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number]
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

?

**2. (продолжение пункта 1)** В документации на [Изменения в работе v-model](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) приведен пример

```
// ChildComponent.vue

export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: String // раньше было `value: String`
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  methods: {
    changePageTitle(title) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', title) // раньше было `this.$emit('input', title)`
    }
  }
}
```

Но необходимо, чтобы код имел вид, как для **объявления (экспорта) `my-input`**

```
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue" @input="updateInput" class="input" type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-input',
  props: {
    modelValue: [String, Number]
  },
  methods: {
    updateInput(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Подскажите как переписать `ChildComponent` нужным образом.

Мне **нужно** для вызова компонента `ChildComponent` c атрибутом title

```
<ChildComponent v-model:title="pageTitle" />
```

написать **export (внутри ChildComponent)** аналогично как для **`my-input`**.

***Мой пример объявления (экспорта) компонента `ChildComponent`***

**P. S.** Я подумал и написал следующий код для `ChildComponent` (код вызова)

```
<ChildComponent
    v-model:title="pageTitle"
/>
```

и код объявления

```
<template>
  <input :value="title" @input="updateInput" class="input" type="text">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'child-component',
    props: {
        title: String
    },
    methods: {
        updateInput(event) {
            this.$emit('update:title', $event.target.value);
        }
    }
  }  
</script>
```

Правилен ли он (правильно ли я понял синтаксис)? Если нет, то приведите правильные (для разных версий vue).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148135/discussion-on-question-by-hpwebsearch-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.